# loading a a csv file in a java program

Tags: java, csv

When I try to run this benchmark [java8-lambda-benchmark](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/an_embedded_java_8_lambda).

Using the comand:

```
java -cp build/jar/LambdaMicrobench.jar lambdademo.LambdaAvgExtraParallel 50000
```

I get the following error:

```
lambdademo/load_employees.csv: Not found in jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
at lambdademo.EmployeeFile.loadEmployeeList(Unknown Source)
at lambdademo.LambdaAvgExtraParallel.main(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at lambdademo.EmployeeFile.loadEmployeeList(Unknown Source)
at lambdademo.LambdaAvgExtraParallel.main(Unknown Source
```

The file EmployeFile.java is the following:

```
public class EmployeeFile {

private static final String EMPLOYEE_FILE = "lambdademo/load_employees.csv";

public LinkedList<EmployeeRec> loadEmployeeList() {
    LinkedList<EmployeeRec> employeeList = new LinkedList<>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
         URL fileURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(EMPLOYEE_FILE);
          if (fileURL == null) {
                   System.out.println("resource is null");
             }
          InputStream in = fileURL.openStream();
          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));             
               } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(EMPLOYEE_FILE + ": Not found in jar");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {    
            String[] rec = null;
            rec = line.split(",");
            employeeList.add(new EmployeeRec(rec[0], rec[1], rec[2],
                    rec[3], rec[4], rec[5]));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading " + EMPLOYEE_FILE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return employeeList;
}
```

Now I print the value of fileURL I get null.
The `csv` file is within the same folder as the sources for the project.

Comment: How do you create the `LambdaMicrobench.jar` (e.g. using an IDE, maven, ant, ... )? Can you confirm that the `.csv` is at the right location _inside_ the `.jar` (a `.jar` is a `.zip` file, just use 7zip/unzip/tar or a similar tool to unpack its content)?

Comment: I built with ant : `ant -buildfile build.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getResource()` method works with the classpath. In your example classpath, you have only the jar, so whatever is outside of the jar can't be found.

You can either open up the jar with the zip tool of your choice and put the .csv file in, or an easier solution add the directory where the csv file is into the classpath with `java -cp <directory>:build/jar/LambdaMicrobench.jar lambdademo.LambdaAvgExtraParallel 50000`.

Note that the `:` separator needs to be `;` if you're on windows.

Comment: the csv file in in this folder src/lambdademo but using this command I still get the same error as before`java -cp src/lambdademo:build/jar/LambdaMicrobench.jar lambdademo.LambdaAvgExtraParallel 50000`

Comment: Just use `src`, the `lambdademo` part seems to be defined already in `EMPLOYEE_FILE`.

Answer (score 2):

when I use `jar -xvf build/jar/LambdaMicrobench.jar` 
I get this output

```
 created: META-INF/
inflated: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 created: lambdademo/
inflated: lambdademo/Constants.class
inflated: lambdademo/EmployeeFile.class
inflated: lambdademo/EmployeeRec.class
inflated: lambdademo/LambdaAvgExtraParallel.class
inflated: lambdademo/LambdaAvgExtraSerial.class
inflated: lambdademo/LambdaAvgParallel.class
inflated: lambdademo/LambdaAvgSerial.class
inflated: lambdademo/OldSchoolAvg.class
inflated: lambdademo/OldSchoolAvgExtra.class
inflated: load_employees.csv
```

These are correct as the project file structure is:

```
--LambdaMicrobench
----load_employees.csv
----lambdademo
------*.class
```

The solution is to change that field,`load_employees.csv` instead of `lambdademo/load_employees.csv`

```
private static final String EMPLOYEE_FILE = "load_employees.csv";
```

Comment: IF the csv is at the root of the jar, then the path should be String EMPLOYEE_FILE = "load_employees.csv"; why do you reference the folder if it isn't in it?